# How to get all cache data using reactjs @apollo/client v3

Tags: react-apollo, apollo-client

Is there anyway that I can check all the cache, eg: changes within apollo for debugging.
Something like redux store, where you can view the whole state tree.

They mentioned:

> The cache stores the objects by ID in a flat lookup table.
> https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/

Any way to display/console the whole lookup table?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For @apollo/client v3

Found the answer, if anyone is interested.

1. Through `InMemoryCache`

You can console log the cache object where you create with InMemoryCache.
You should be able to find it under your created cache:

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({"...Your option"})
console.log(cache.data) // <- Your cache query
```

2. Through `browser console`

Through browser, use console to log `data`

```
__APOLLO_CLIENT__.cache.data
```

3. Through `apollo` v3

Access through apollo client cache

```
const client = useApolloClient();
const serializedState = client.cache.extract();
console.log(serializedState) <- your cache query
```

Comment: On `v2` `console.log(cache.data)` returns an object that looks like: `cache:  DepTrackingCache {
      data: [Object: null prototype] {},
      depend: { [Function: optimistic] dirty: [Function] } }`

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I have edited the answer to tag the answer is for v3.

Comment: The `data` attribute is set as a private attribute of the `InMemoryCache` class, therefore we can't access it like shown in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Apollo Client extension for Chrome, seem to work, there is now "Apollo" tab in the dev tools

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apollo-client-devtools/jdkknkkbebbapilgoeccciglkfbmbnfm?hl=en-US

I used "readQuery" method to get data from cache, might be not best way to do it.

```
import { useApolloClient, gql } from '@apollo/client';
```

...

```
const WEBSITE_TITLE = gql`
  query GetSitewide {
    sitewide {
      data {
        attributes {
          header {
            __typename
            id
            siteTitle
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

...

```
function WebsiteTitle() {
  const client = useApolloClient();
  const {
    sitewide: {
      data: {
        attributes: { header },
      },
    },
  } = client.readQuery({
    query: WEBSITE_TITLE,
  });

  const { siteTitle } = header;

  return <> {siteTitle} </>;
}

export default WebsiteTitle;
```